# Unable to associate an ncurses form with a window

Tags: c++, ncurses

I am trying to associate an `ncurses` form with a window. Here is the complete code of my trial:

```
#include <form.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main() {
    initscr();
    cbreak();
    noecho();
    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);

    FORM  *myform;
    std::vector<FIELD *> fields;

    fields.push_back(new_field(1, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0));
    set_field_back(fields[0], A_UNDERLINE);
    fields.push_back(nullptr);
    myform = new_form(fields.data());

    WINDOW *mypad = newpad(5, 20);
    set_form_win(myform, mypad); // no effect?
    post_form(myform);
    prefresh(mypad, 0, 0, 10, 10, 20, 20); // no effect...

    getch();
    unpost_form(myform);
    free_form(myform);
    free_field(fields[0]);
    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

As the comments indicate, calling `set_form_win` does not seem to have any effect. The form is displayed in the top left corner regardless of the arguments I supply to `prefresh`. A similar code worked with menus just fine, but it would not work with a form. What am I missing?

As an additional detail, the form gets magically displayed even without a call to `prefresh` or any other function from the `refresh` family.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows and pads are similar, but they are not the same.  The [`set_form_win`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/form_win.3x.html) function expects a window.

The [`newpad`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_pad.3x.html#h3-newpad) manual page notes:

> It is not legal to call  [wrefresh](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_refresh.3x.html)
>   with  a  pad  as  an  argument;  the  routines [prefresh](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_pad.3x.html#h3-prefresh_-pnoutrefresh) or
>   pnoutrefresh should be called instead.

The form library does use pads — internally, for *fields* — but the windows are just that (no pads).  The relevant functions are [wcursyncup](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_window.3x.html#h3-wcursyncup) and [wsyncup](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_window.3x.html#h3-wsyncup) (it relies on [`wgetch`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_getch.3x.html#h3-Reading-characters) for the application for the actual [`wrefresh`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_refresh.3x.html) calls).

Comment: I do call `prefresh`, don't I? If you were able to get my example to work, could you please post your code?

Comment: The form library doesn't call `prefresh`, which is the problem you ran into.

Comment: Ah. Got it. You are saying that what I am trying to achieve (i.e. put a form into a pad) is impossible, right?

Comment: Right - it's not designed to put a form into a pad.